# How to upgrade a remote box from 10.10 to 12.04 LTS when apt doesn't work?

Tags: 12.04, apt, upgrade, 10.10, remote

I have a virtual private server that runs the out-of-date Ubuntu 10.10. I'd like to upgrade to 12.04 LTS.

Currently `apt` doesn't work on this box, and the command `do-release-upgrade` is not found.

There is nothing on this VPS that I need to save, I'm OK with wiping it clean and installing 12.04, but I don't know how to do that when my only access is to a terminal remotely.

Comment: What does not work with `apt-get`? What error do you get? I think it is possible to upgrade from LTS to LTS.

Comment: I'm not upgrading from LTS to LTS, but from 10.10 to 12.04.

Comment: I don't think that this is a dup of the linked question. As I specified, the `do-release-upgrade` command is not found.

Comment: And the answer says how to install it...

Comment: @Braiam Good point. But with `apt` broken, and with this being a remote server, it is far from obvious to me how I would install `do-release-upgrade`.

Comment: Do you have ftp server or wget command in the remote system? You can download them from http://packages.ubuntu.com/update-manager-core (I didn't found the specific packages) or use the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how would one go about wiping and reinstalling Ubuntu remotely, but you could try the following to upgrade remotely, without `apt` and `do-release-upgrade`.

1. Download the "Alternate CD" for 12.04.3 LTS server edition using:

   For 64-bit:

   ```
   wget http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-12.04.3-alternate-amd64.iso
   ```

   For 32-bit:

   ```
   wget http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-12.04.3-alternate-i386.iso
   ```
2. Mount it to `/media/cdrom` using:

   ```
   sudo mount -o loop ubuntu-12.04.3-alternate-amd64.iso /media/cdrom
   ```
3. Run the following command to start the upgrade:

   ```
   sh /media/cdrom/cdromupgrade
   ```

   Or, if you're not root:

   ```
   gksu "sh '/media/cdrom/cdromupgrade'"
   ```

**Note 1**: I don't know if it's possible to directly upgrade from 10.10 to 12.04. I think you'll need to go through the releases in between, one by one.

**Note 2**: I haven't tried the above steps before, so I'm not sure if it will work. But according to this: [PreciseUpgrade](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PreciseUpgrades), it should. The steps there indicate to mount the `.iso` file to "the exact name of the CD", but I'm not sure what the exact name of the CD is on 10.10.

Comment: `gksu` in a cli environment? Nice! BTW, you should add that answer to the main question ;).

Comment: I haven't tried this, so not accepting. Found a way to fix apt (pointing to old-releases) which is solving my problem for now.